# Rails: Computed Column in Master based on Detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few tables in Master-Detail form.

```
create_table "invoice" do |t|
  t.integer  "serial_no"
  t.decimal  "amount"
end

create_table "line" do |t|
  t.integer  "item_id"
  t.decimal  "amount"
end

create_table "discount" do |t|
  t.integer  "discount_type_id"
  t.decimal  "amount"
end
```

with a has_many relation from Invoice to Lines and Discounts.

```
has_many :lines, inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy
has_many :discounts, inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy
```

**UPDATE**: Perhaps I should add that I am pulling the entire information through nested attributes

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :discounts, allow_destroy: true
```

All tables have an amount column, and I would like to aggregate the amount column in Invoice on save.

```
def calculate_invoice_amount
  self.amount = line.sum(:amount) - discount.sum(:amount)
end
```

But this does not work as Line record is (probably) saved after Invoice record.

Is there a standard approach to update master table with calculated values from detail tables?

PS: One of the responses I expect is that it is always possible to rollup the amount from Line, but having more dependent tables, it would become cumbersome if there are frequent querying for aggregated information

Answer (score 0):

You can use [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_invoice

  private
    def update_invoice
      self.invoice.calculate_invoice_amount if amount_changed?
    end
end

class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_invoice

  private
    def update_invoice
      self.invoice.calculate_invoice_amount if amount_changed?
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried before_save :sum_lines ? Initially I made mistake and wrote before_create.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. I just added a bit more context to the question. I am using nested attributes to pull the lines and discounts through Invoice.

Comment: I changed my answer a little, maybe this will help you more

Comment: That's interesting. Just now i have come up with another solution using after_save and update_column (to skip further callbacks). I will test this out as well

Comment: One potential problem I see is that Invoice record gets inserted before Line or Discount gets inserted. So I doubt whether this will work unless we send another update to the master table.

Comment: You need to check, but if you use accepts_nested_attributes_for and save on invoice - in such case transaction flow should works as expected